# Pytorch Siamese NN with BERT for sentence matching

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, bert-language-model, siamese-network

I'm trying to build a Siamese neural network using pytorch in which I feed BERT word embeddings and trying to find whether two sentences are similar or not (imagine duplicate posts matching, product matching etc). Here's the model:

```
class SiameseNetwork(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.brothers = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(512 * 768, 512),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            torch.nn.Linear(512, 256),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            torch.nn.Linear(256, 32),
        )
        
        self.final = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(32, 16),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            torch.nn.Linear(16, 2),
        )
    
    def forward(self, left, right):
        outputLeft = self.brothers(left)
        outputRight = self.brothers(right)
        output = self.final((outputLeft - outputRight) ** 2)
        return output

bros = SiameseNetwork()
bros = bros.to(device)
```

Criterion and optimizer:

```
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=bros.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

The training loop:

```
for batch in tqdm(tLoader, desc=f"Train epoch: {epoch+1}"):
        a = batch[0].to(device)
        b = batch[1].to(device)
        y = torch.unsqueeze(batch[2].type(torch.FloatTensor), 1).to(device)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        output = bros(a,b)
        loss = criterion(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        
        trainingLoss += loss.item()

        optimizer.step()
```

Now, this seems to be working, as it produces results that are reasonable, but the validation error stops dropping at 0.13 after just a of epochs. Can't find a lot of things on this kind of NNs using Pytorch. Are there ways to optimize it? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first layer is severely overparameterized and prone to overfitting (counts a total of 201 million parameters). I assume the shape `512 * 768` reflects the number of tokens times their dimensionality; if that's the case, you need to rethink your architecture. You need some sort of weight sharing or pooling strategy to reduce the `num_words * dim` input to a fixed representation (that's exactly why recurrent networks replaced the fully-connected varieties for sentence encoding). Specifically in transformer-based architectures, the `[CLS]` token (token number 0, prefixing the input) is typically used as the "summary" token for sequence- and bisequence-level tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you direct me to some good Pytorch ways to implement those strategies?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the bert paper on sequence/bisequence-level predictions. If you prefer reading code, there's quite a few pop implementations to refer to, see e.g. [this](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification). The general idea is that you dont employ a siamese BERT, but rather feed BERT two sequences separated by a special `[SEP]` token. This allows the model to freely attend between the two sentences' tokens, and constructs a contextualized representation in the `[CLS]` token that you can feed into your classifier.

Comment: (cont) You can then *fine-tune* BERT, i.e. jointly train its internal weights, together with your custom classifier, on your downstream task.

Comment: Max pooling seriously reduced the model size, which is great. Having both sequences pass through is unfortunately computationally bad for my use-case, I'm trying to understand these concepts for a competition with certain hardware that runs the end solution and it's CPU only. It's lighter to run BERT on 300 sentences and play with the results rather that run all sentence pairs.